# Type not recognized for tag in macro definition

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, debugging, sdk

I'm defining a macro in [insert programming/markup language here] that includes a tag called ?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall. However, I'm getting an error that says "Can't determine type for tag".

I've double-checked the syntax of my macro definition and everything seems to be formatted correctly. I'm not sure what else could be causing this issue.

Could it be related to a missing library or dependency? Or is there something else I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I tried changing dependencies and updating the sdk versions, but it did not work.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're talking about. What do you mean by "macro"? Why are you censoring which language you're using? The error is going to be specific to whatever framework and/or language you're using, so we can't interpret its meaning without knowing that.